# Visual Basic do while loop with inputbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program where the user enters positive numbers. The user can enter as much as he or she wants. However, if the user enters a negative or 0 value, the program ends.

The program will also calculate the average based on the number of time the user has entered. It will also have to print the minimum and maximum number that the user has provided. For example, if the user enter the following string of numbers: 5, 4, 9, 11, 15, 2, The minimum number is 2 and the maximum number is 15.

Anyway, the problem I'm having is that the program only displays the average and the maximum number. I can't figure out how to display the minimum value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnGetNumbers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetNumbers.Click
        Dim min As Integer ,max As Integerm, count As Integer 'Declare variables
        Dim total As Integer,average As Double, num As Integer 
        max = num 'Store the max vaule
        min = num 'Store the min vaule
        count = 0 'Set the count value
        total = 0  'Set the total value
        Do 'Start the loop
            Dim response = InputBox("Enter numbers", "Enter numbers") 'Ask the user for input numbers
            total = total + num 'Find the value
            count = count + 1  'Increment the count
            If num > max Then max = num 'set max value if number is max
            If num < min Then min = num 'set min value if number is min
            num = response 'Read the number of the user input
        Loop While num > 0  'The loop ends here
        average = CDbl(total) / CDbl(count) 'Find the average value
        txtMinimum.Text = min 'Display the min value
        txtMaximum.Text = max 'Display the max value
        txtAverage.Text = average 'Display the average value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: easy. You initalize your minimum nr as 0 but 0 is not allowed bc of your game rules. And bc 0 is always lower than any other nr it will never be overwritten. I would change "max = num" to "max =0" and "min = num" to "min = 32,767"

Comment: and honestly I would change the loop a little. your code is breaking, after the iteration is done. so if the user has put in a wrong nr, it is being evaluated. so if you change "Loop While num > 0" to "Loop" and include "If num <= 0 Then Exit Do" after the user input this problem is solved.

Comment: and as this is vb.net code and not vba-code, I would set "min = 2,147,483,647"

Comment: min = Integer.MaxValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that `num` (and therefore `min`) are initalized to 0.  Since your program (by design) ends if a value <= 0 is entered, `min` is never updated since every user entry is > 0.  Further, if the use enters 0 to end the process... it becomes the minimum.  Give this edited version of your example a try:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        'Declare minimum variable
        Dim min As Integer
        'Declare maximum variable
        Dim max As Integer
        'Declare count variable
        Dim count As Integer
        'Declare total variable
        Dim total As Integer
        'Declare average variable
        Dim average As Double
        'Declare number variable
        Dim num As Integer



        'Store the max value
        max = num

        'Store the min value
        min = 32767 'initialize to the maximum possible Int value rather than 0

        'Set the count value
        count = 0

        'Set the total value
        total = 0

        'Start the loop
        Do

            'Ask the user for input numbers
            'Dim response = InputBox("Enter numbers", "Enter numbers")

            Dim response As String
            response = InputBox("Enter numbers", "Enter numbers")

            num = CInt(response)

            If num > 0 Then 'avoid overwriting the min

                'Find the value
                total = total + num

                'Increment the count
                count = count + 1

                'Check if the number is max
                If num > max Then
                    'Set the max value
                    max = num
                End If

                'Check if the number is min
                If num < min Then
                    'Set the value of min
                    min = num
                End If

            End If

            'The loop ends here
        Loop While num >= 1

        If count > 0 Then
            'Find the average value
            average = CDbl(total) / CDbl(count)

            'Display the min value
            'txtMinimum.Text = min
            MsgBox "Min = " & CStr(min)

            'Display the max value
            'txtMaximum.Text = max
            MsgBox "Max = " & CStr(max)

            'Display the average value
            'txtAverage.Text = average
            MsgBox "Avg = " & CStr(average)
        End If

    End Sub
```